# Chain relation in three variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I would like to prove the following identity, where $x,y,z$ are linked by a functional relation $f(x,y,z)=0$ and where the parentheses denote differentiation while keeping the indicated variable constant:

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y=-1
\end{equation}

Can you help?

Comment: For searching purposes: this chain relation is often attributed to Euler;  thus the terms "Euler relation" or "Euler chain relation" are sometimes used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_t=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ for $t$ in $\{x,y,z\}$, then
$$
\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z=-\frac{A_y}{A_x},\qquad\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)_x=-\frac{A_z}{A_y},\qquad\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y=-\frac{A_x}{A_z}.
$$
The result follows.

To prove the first identity for example, assume that $x=x^*+a$, $y=y^*+b$ and $z=z^*$ solve $f(x,y,z)=0$ with $a\to0$ and $b\to0$. Then $\dfrac{a}b\to\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z$ and
$$
0=f(x^*+a,y^*+b,z^*)-f(x^*,y^*,z^*)=aA_x+bA_y+o((a,b)),
$$
hence
$$
\dfrac{a}b\to-\dfrac{A_y}{A_x}.
$$

Comment: isn't $\dfrac{a}b$ going to $+\dfrac{A_y}{A_x}$ instead of $-\dfrac{A_y}{A_x}$?

Comment: @sjdh No. Solve the linear case.

Comment: sorry, I copied the wrong formulae from you post. I meant Isn't $\dfrac{a}b\to$ going to $+\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z$ instead of $-\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z$

Comment: @sjdh You are right. Well done! (Thanks, post modified.)